# Overwriting state when loaded from props

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props

I have this code, or the relevant parts at least....

```
class ClubDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      clubBetsPending: this.props.pendingBets,
    }
    this.updatePbd = this.updatePbd.bind(this)
  }

  static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
    const props = axios
      .post('http://localhost:3000/api/club', { clubId: query.clubid })
      .then((res) => {
        //pass response to UI

        if (res.data.response.boolean) {
          return {
            pendingBets: res.data.payload,
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        //Not Found
      })

    return props
  }

  updatePbd(newBet) {
    var newPbd = [newBet[0]].concat(this.state.clubBetsPending)
    this.setState({ clubBetsPending: newPbd })
  }

  render() {
     return ( <>
        <NewBet updatePbd={this.updatePbd} />
        <PendingBets data={this.state.clubBetsPending} />
        </>
     )
  }
```

From what I have read my render isn't running when it hits the setState in updatePbd because the state is being recieved from the props `this.props.pendingBets`. So I understand the problem, i just don't understand what the solution is?

Can someone help, I can't find anything for this problem or I don't know what to search for.
Thanks

Comment: Copy props into state is discouraged because if `this.props.pendingBets` changes his value from parent component, child does not update his state (because constructor will run once). But I don't think this is the reason why you render is not fired after state update. Maybe the problem is on `PendingBets`... How do you manage props update in `PendingBets`?

Comment: Oh thanks for the help. I was actually doing the same with props in 'PendingBets' so instead of this.props. i was saying this.state. Wasn't necessary to pass it into state instead of just using props. Works now <3